# My for loop is executing more times than is expected

Tags: c++, loops

I have the following `for` loop executing within my program and I can't see how it's design correlates with the output I'm receiving.

```
cout << no_of_lines << endl;
for (int count = 0; count < no_of_lines + 1; count ++)
{
    getline(Device, line, '=');
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

This is the output:

```
3
DeviceName
GPU
Manufacturer
Intel
GraphicalRam
128MB
```

And this is the file DeviceList

```
DeviceName=GPU
Manufacturer=Intel 
GraphicalRam=128MB
```

In the loop, `no_of_lines` refers to the number of lines in the file, in this case 3. I have provided this output as verification that the loop is only executing once per line. Can anyone tell me why this loop is executing more times than is expected? I'm guessing it's because of my inclusion of `=` as the deliminator, and that the loop is somehow executing an additional time before incrementing, but then why does it stop on the deliminator on the last line, requiring me to add 1 to the loop limit?

Comment: As per http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/ your code should read `DeviceList.getline(line, 255, '=');`. Am I missing something?

Comment: That output does not match the code and the input. There is something else that you are not showing us. We need a compilable example that when we run it shows the problem. I bet that as you make this example you will fix your own problem.

Comment: @Mikhail: No. There is a std::getline() that takes a stream, string and a separator and this is what you should (normally) be using (your version requires lines to be less than the buffer size and is pain if they are not) see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/ is your friend here. The documentation says that when delem character is passed to getline, it reads up to delem char is found or end of file is reached. '\n' is not treated differently. Once it find delem char it discards it and fills *line* whatever it read until that point. Next time you call getline, it continues to read from where it left. so in this case, each call reads as follows.

```
DeviceName
GPU\nManufacturer
Intel\nGraphicalRam
128MB\n
```

'\n' in the above string is basically newline character. it's not really backslash followed by n (2 characters). its just single newline character '\n'. Just for understanding purposes I used it that way.

For clarity, here is the complete code(compiled and tested).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int no_of_lines = 3;
    string line;
    cout << no_of_lines << endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < no_of_lines + 1; count++)
    {
        getline(cin, line, '=');
        cout << line << endl ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By now I hope its clear to you why you need to call getline 4 times.

Comment: Yeah, everything's clear now. I wasn't thinking about the '\n' in the way the compiler saw it, which would be just another character. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Re "it's not really \n", it really is. i suspect what you want to say that it's not literally a backslash followed by lowercase n, but a single newline character. Cheers,

Comment: To avoid future confusion in cases like these debug yourself with `cout << "(" << line << ")" << endl;`

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll also trying and avoid doing so at 3:30am :P. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

your loop executes `no_of_lines+1` times.

I assume you want the delimiter to be '='. However, when the delimiter is '=', then `\n` is not a delimiter. Hence `line` will contain `\n` (say, on the second `getline`). And so the number of lines displayed is not equal to the number of times the loop executes.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `=` as line delimiter, `\n` is *not* used as line delimiter.

So you get strings *containing* newline characters.

When you output such a string, it's presented as two or more lines (due to the newlines it contains).

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

You want it to count thrice, but your loop is counting 0,1,2,3,4, i.e 5 iterations.

Comment: it's not 5, it's from 0 to less than 4, so 0,1,2,3 = 4 times.

Comment: @Mikhail: hm, so it is. i sit corrected. :-) still, it's useful to OP to know that the loop executes more times than the number of lines.